# SFTP user creation in Windows OpenSSH

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-access, sftp, users

We have installed an SFTP server as per
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server
Now we are able to connect via WinSCP and FileZilla.

But by default, account login to SFTP is Windows account and path is `c:/users/useraccount`.
How to give access to users for SFTP and login without a Windows account?

Please help.

Comment: Nothing requires you to use OpenSSH server.  If you truly don't want to use Windows accounts for authentication (which, besides public keys, is all OpenSSH supports for Windows) you should search for a different SFTP server.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH does not have any built-in account management functionality.

It by default relies on the system authentication. Both on Linux and Windows.

*(You might build a PAM module to provide your custom authentication. But that's not a question for this site.)*